# USB Mouse sleeping after 5 seconds when on battery

Tags: usb, mouse, power-management, sleep

My usb mouse sleeps after 5 seconds of inactivity when running on battery power.
It wakes uo again when i press any button on the mouse. This is really annoying.

I have made lsusb, and I noticed my mouse is

`Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04d9:2083 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.`

I have checked my `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/autosuspend` but it is already set to 0, and the directory `usb1` has many subdirectories which also have autosuspend files, and i dont know how to edit them.

Also, I would like a permanent solution, which would work for any mouse, on any of my 3 usb ports. Any ideas?

Using: `Ubuntu 12.04 64bit`

Answer (score 22):

To solve this problem on 12.04 and continue using laptop-mode-tools
edit the file:

/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf
```

And look for the line:

```
AUTOSUSPEND_USBTYPE_BLACKLIST=""
```

Replace with:

```
AUTOSUSPEND_USBTYPE_BLACKLIST="usbhid usb-storage"
```

This will automatically disable USB autosuspend if you have ANY mouse and even USB drives plugged in.

Comment: Awesome tip!!! Thanks :) Also it is possible to add device by id like 0458:003a

Comment: hi i could not edit the file due to permissions..plzz help me..i am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: In the same file, I just set AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT=600 since 2 seconds is a little nutty anyway.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, the config file is called `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf` and the property is named `AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVTYPE`.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, I think after I installed either `laptop-mode-tools` or `powertop`. Instead of uninstalling them again...

- enter `sudo powertop` in a terminal
- use the right arrow key to change to the tab *Tunables*
- use the down arrow key to select the line with `Autosuspend` for your USB mouse
- press Enter to toggle this line to `Bad`
- quit powertop with the key q

EDIT:
Too bad, this is just a temporary solution. It does not survive a reboot...

However, I found something else. If you have `laptop-mode-tools` installed, try to set
`CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0` in the file `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf`

EDIT: setting BATT_SUSPEND_USB=0 should also solve the problem (at least it solved mine).

Answer (score 4):

The following link offers another approach that looks like it should work.  Just attempted it myself.  Here's hoping.

In case the link goes away I'll give you the short and sweet version.  First off, the fix assumes you're using laptop-mode-tools.  Use `lsusb` to get the id of the device, and then add this to the `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST` parameter in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf`.

The id I'm using for my USB mouse has been highlighted in the below snippet from `lsusb`'s output.

`Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0748 Microsoft Corp.`

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/06/fix-usb-mouse-not-working-laptop-mode-tools-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

use `lsusb` to find bus number and device number
next in each folder present in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` which is named as `number-number` such as `1-1.2` etc check the files `busnum` and `devnum` to find the bus number and device number the files are for and find the folder required (say `1-1.2`).

Next for the respective folder say `1-1.2`, set the value in file located at  `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/power/autosuspend` as `-1`.
Now the device will not suspend.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is temporary solution.

Comment: This could be non-temporary if added to one of the system init scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the `laptop-mode-tools` or `powertop` packages installed. If you do, uninstall them by running

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge laptop-mode-tools powertools && apt-get autoremove
```

This solved the issue for me on Mint 13 on an Alienware M14x R2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `powertop`. I just realized I didn't have this problem before installing it. Your command isn't correct on Ubuntu, it should have been: `sudo apt-get remove --purge powertop-1.13 && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo pico /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` to edit the mentioned file.

Search the line

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="auto"
```

and remove "auto", so that it reads

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=""
```

Worked for me.