# WIreless mouse stop working for few sec

Tags: wireless, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and my Logitech M510 wireless mouse stop working for few sec after not moving it for few sec. I changed the batteries for new one but the issue is still present. I'm using it on my laptop since playing Minecraft with a touch pad is not recommended.

If I keep moving the mouse around, it will work, but it is only when I stop touching it for like 3 seconds that it freeze for 1 or 2 seconds, even more sometime.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your mouse is most likely auto sleeping after a given delay.

Logitech says that the M510 should have a 15-30 second delay before sleeping, so I don't think it's the mouse's problem alone.

It's possible that you're experiencing general autosuspend for USB devices.

Hopefully these links help:

[How to disable auto power off of usb devices like usb mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse)

[USB Mouse sleeping after 5 seconds when on battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141832/usb-mouse-sleeping-after-5-seconds-when-on-battery)