# USB Mouse Sleeping in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, usb, mouse, suspend

First of all, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141832/usb-mouse-sleeping-after-5-seconds-when-on-battery%22question%22)

My USB mouse is sleeping after three seconds and I have to click to wake it up. This is a system which was upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. I was using laptop mode tools in 14.04 and I was facing the same issue there. I applied the fix mentioned in the above question by blacklisting my usb mouse id.

The fix was working untill I upgraded to 16.04. Currently the configuration change in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` is not correcting this behaviour.

Is there anything else which is handling auto suspend in 16.04? What can I do to fix this?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that this is not happening in every reboots. If the mouse is sleeping it will sleep till I power off. The next boot may or may not have the issue.

I have also tried changing `CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0` in the file `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` without any success.

This is the output of the grep command.

```
me@mypc:~$dpkg --get-selections | grep powertop
me@mypc:~$
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that isn't a duplicate question? What's the output of  `dpkg --get-selections | grep powertop` ?

Comment: The same fix is not working in this case. That is why I am saying that it is not a duplicate question. There are no lines as output for the command.

Comment: Did you try ALL the answers there or only the one you mentioned? Please [edit] your post and provide the output of the command as requested. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved this. The solutions mentioned in the other threads assume that the auto suspend is done by laptop mode tools or powertop.The auto suspend behaviour here is caused by the Linux Kernel.
This can be overcome by adding a device specific rule

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/usb-power.rules
```

Add the following lines in the file

```
#Wheel Mouse Optical
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="045e", ATTR{idProduct}=="0040", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```

use lsusb to find your device id and vendor id and replace them in the above code.

SOURCE: http://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/